# layout figure and figurecaption horizontally

Tags: css, html

I am using figure and figcaption in a Django template but cannot get them to be laid out horizontally. The figures are laid our vertically and I would like a horizontal layout.

The code is as follows:

```
<div class="container">
    <figure>
        <a href="logout">
            <img src="{% static "workflow-icon.png" %}" alt="A"/>
        </a>
        <figcaption><a href="A">Execute function A</a></figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure>
        <a href="logout">
            <img src="{% static "review-icon.png" %}" alt="B"/>
        </a>
        <figcaption><a href="B">Execute function B</a></figcaption>                          
    </figure>
 </div>
```

The relevant CSS:

```
figure img {
    vertical-align: top;
}
figure figcaption {
    border: 1px dotted blue;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Georgia;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: The answer is probably "use CSS to style the elements", no? A combination of `float: left;` and defined widths should work

Comment: @Pekka웃 Thanks for that. I am very new to this stuff, so had no idea what was available. I will look into this.

Comment: Please add the CSS you've tried.

Comment: <figcaption> has `display: block` by default, so all you need to do is change that to `display: inline` or `display: inline-block`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) can help you here. In your css, if you add:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
}
```

and delete:

```
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
```

that gives you what I believe you've described. I've created this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dacmo/8Lkp37Lh/1/) from your code, incorporating my code suggestion, so you can see how it works.